# jQuery - alert if no option chosen doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function where when you click the "play" button, the options and the button disappear.

I have tried to add an `if` statement that says if nothing was selected then an alerts appears on the screen and the game doesn't start. However, this is not working.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#options').change(function() { // NOTE: all themes have capital letters on colors
    if ($(this).val() === 'Dark') {
      $("#game").css("background-color", "black");
      $("#player").css({
        "background-color": "white" // using CSS function in case you want to add other stuff
      });
    }
    if ($(this).val() === 'Light') {
      $("#game").css("background-color", "white");
      $("#player").css({
        "background-color": "black" // using CSS function in case you want to add other stuff
      });
    }
  });

  $("#play").click(function() {
    if ($("#options").val != "none") { // NOTE: not working
      $(this).hide();
      $("#options").hide();
      $("#player").show();
    } else if ($("#options").val === "none") {
      alert("You haven't selected a theme")
    }
  });


});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#main_title {
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #999999;
}
.block {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
}
#game {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 550px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  margin: 2% 10%;
  position: relative;
}
#player {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
#play {
  padding: 1%;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}
#options {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Trash Fall - Game</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- adding jQuery to the script -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="main_title">Color Drop</h1>



  <button id="play">Play</button>
  <select id="options">
    <option value="none">none (choose one in order to play)</option>
    <option value="Dark">Dark</option>
    <option value="Light">Light</option>
    <option value="Blue_White">Blue/White</option>
    <option value="Red_White">Red/White</option>
  </select>

  <div id="game">

    <div id="player"></div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

---

Why isn't this working?

Comment: `$("#options").val` - > `$("#options").val()`. [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is a method and not a property. You probably  just missed that or forgot to put them in.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek thank you! I feel so dumb now... :(

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek post it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, although I do feel like this is more of a typo.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek No no no! not a typo at all! Just that I am clumsy and I don't pay attention enough! please, I would be glad to validate it!

Comment: Alright then, I just mean that it's clear you knew that already and it was just a mistake and you forgot to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code on this line:

```
if ($("#options").val != "none") { // NOTE: not working
    ...
```

You are are using `.val` as it was a property. Although it's a method ( [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) ):

```
if ($("#options").val() != "none") { // `val` --> `val()`
   ...
```

You seem to clearly already know that; you likely just forgot or missed the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Use script like this , **$("#options").val()** instead of **$("#options").val** and **no need else if condition**

```
  $("#play").click(function() {
    if ($("#options").val() != "none") { // NOTE: not working
      $(this).hide();
      $("#options").hide();
      $("#player").show();
    }else {
      alert("You haven't selected a theme")
    }
  });
```